# MVC 5 Remote Validator - call web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I built a remote validator (controller -> action) and decorated the field with the Remote attribute that points to the action and controller.

The action itself will take the value entered by user and call a remote service. The service will return true or false.

If the response is false then the remote validation returns false and the error message is shown.

The problem is that it works fine except that the input is not validated after the focus is lost on the field but after the form is submitted. Basically the form is submitted, hit's the controller action but the validation of the value occurs after submit and then the error message is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your web.config has this set

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
```

And for a cleaner output, you may also want to try enabling the unobtrusive validation as well.

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Just make sure your project has those javascript files included, they should have been added via Nuget